# what is the best way to create connection Class in C#

Tags: c#, get, set, connection-string

I have windows form that asking user name, password and databaseName, and the way I am using to connect database open to SQL injection!.
I want to create different class for my connection string, also want to use get and set methods if it is necessary. what is the best way to do that?

Thanks?

***my Connection String***

```
  string db1 = "Data Source=" + txtDatabase.Text + ";User Id=" + txtUserID.Text.ToUpper() + ";Password=" + txtUserPassword.Text + ";";
```

Comment: Why would you say the connection string above is open to SQL Injection?

Comment: @astander maybe meant that it was open to be altered which not necesarily means SQL INJECTION which can only be considered when its a SQL COMMAND

Comment: @Mauricio, so there is no sql injection for oracle connection?\

Comment: @user2661591 SQL INJECTION happens when an input from the user can affect a SQL COMMAND that is going to be executed. What you have there is a connection string than can me altered incorreclty by the user but no SQL command is being executed, therefore is not CALLED SQL INJECTION but its highly recommend that the values input by the user are validated before using the answer provided by Geek

Answer (score 1):

connection builder

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder =
  new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder["Data Source"] = "(local)";
builder["integrated Security"] = true;
builder["Initial Catalog"] = "AdventureWorks;NewValue=Bad";
Console.WriteLine(builder.ConnectionString);
```